# Filter Customers by Date Created in WooCommerce REST API

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm attempting to retrieve customer data from WooCommerce using the REST API, filtered by the date of creation. I've tried two different approaches, but neither seems to work. Here's what I've tried:

Using the `date_created` parameter:

```
{{base_url}}/wc/v3/customers/?date_created=2023-12-18 08:36:18
```

Using the after parameter:

```
{{base_url}}/wc/v3/customers/?after=2023-12-18 08:36:18
```

In both cases, it appears that I'm not getting the expected results. Is there a specific date format I should be using, or is there another method to achieve this?

Could anyone point me in the right direction for filtering WooCommerce customers by date created using their REST API?

Thank you in advance for any help!

**Edit**

I am looking for a solution without access to the source code

**Edit_2**

[image]

Comment: If you go to [Documentation for WooCommerce Rest API V3 > Customer > Retrieve a customer](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#retrieve-a-customer) you will see that the date format is like `2023-12-18T08:36:18` and the variable attribute is `date_created`, so you should try with `{{base_url}}/wc/v3/customers/?date_created=2023-12-18T08:36:18`

Comment: I try with `T` and without.

Comment: @lo also checked this post but still cant understand how its work via API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561838/woocommerce-rest-api-v3-filter-customers-by-modified-date

Comment: filtering orders by `after` param works with `2023-12-18T08:36:18` and `2023-12-18 08:36:18`  @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 1):

Based on [WooCommerce REST API v3 - Filter customers by modified date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561838/woocommerce-rest-api-v3-filter-customers-by-modified-date/68578406#68578406) answer, add the following code:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_customer_query', 'add_created_before_and_after_filter_to_rest_api', 10, 2);
function add_created_before_and_after_filter_to_rest_api( $prepared_args, $request ) {
    $created_after  = $request->get_param('created_after');
    $created_before = $request->get_param('created_before'); 
    $date_query     = []; // Initialize variable

    if ( $created_after ) {
        $date_query['after'] = date("F jS, Y", strtotime($created_after));
    }

    if ( $created_before ) {
        $date_query['before'] = date("F jS, Y", strtotime($created_before));
    }

    if ( ! empty($date_query) ) {
        $prepared_args['date_query'][] = $date_query;
    }
    return $prepared_args;
}
```

The code normally extends the allowed date time formats…

Then you can try to use `created_after` and `created_before` arguments to query customers before or/and after date(s) like *(here for a date range*):

```
{{base_url}}/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/?created_after=2023-12-17&created_before=2023-12-19
```

It could work *(works for a `WP_User_Query` which is used [just after the filter hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.4/plugins/woocommerce/includes/rest-api/Controllers/Version1/class-wc-rest-customers-v1-controller.php#L270-L272))*…

Comment: without adding the code, it is impossible to download the customer by the date of addition/modification? I dont have access to source code. @LoicTheAztec

Comment: sorry I didn't mention the source code issue earlier

Comment: ```{{base_url}}/wc/v3/customers/?after=2023-12-17T00:00:00&before=2023-12-19T00:00:00 ```
returns all customers  @LoicTheAztec

Comment: In my test environment I only modify the Product.php line 7245, but that's it.
In production I don't have access to the code and I thought this was normal behavior and the requests had to be made differently for the customer @LoicTheAztec

Comment: If you have access to the admin (backend), you can add Code snippet plugin, which will allow you to add some custom code… I can't help more than that…

Comment: if it should work by default, I will try to set up the woocommerce environment from scratch, thank you for help.

Comment: I have access to admin panel but just to local env

Comment: now I discovered that in the documentation there is no after and before field for get all customer. Thanks again for your help.